# Why is my MongoDb query inserting an embedded document on Update?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

This is my MongoDB query:

```
db.events.update({date:{$gte: ISODate("2014-09-01T00:00:00Z")}},{$set:{"artists.$.soundcloud_toggle":false}},{multi:true,upsert:false})
```

Apparently I cannot use "artists.$.soundcloud_toggle" to update all artist documents within the artists array:

> "The $ operator can update the first array element that matches
>   multiple query criteria specified with the $elemMatch() operator.
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/"

I'm happy to run the query a number of times changing the index of the array in order to set the soundcloud_toggle property of every artist in every event that matches the query e.g

```
artists.0.soundcloud_toggle
artists.1.soundcloud_toggle
artists.2.soundcloud_toggle
artists.3.soundcloud_toggle
```

The problem is: when there is say, only one artist document in the artists array and I run the query with "artists.1.soundcloud_toggle" It will insert an artist document into the artist array with a single property:

```
{
   "soundcloud_toggle" : true
},
```

(I have declared "upsert:false", which should be false by default anyways)

How do I stop the query from inserting a document and setting soundcloud_toggle:false when there is no existing document there? I only want it to update the property if an artist exists at the given artists array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, like you said, you don't mind completing the operation with multiple queries, you can add an `$exists` condition to your filter.

E.g. in the 5th iteration, when updating index=4, add: `"artists.4": {$exists: true}`, like:

```
db.events.update(
    { date: {$gte: ISODate("2014-09-01T00:00:00Z")},
      "artists.4": {$exists: true} },
    { $set:{ "artists.4.soundcloud_toggle" :false } },
    { multi: true, upsert: false }
)
```